# Stopping Bootstrap .col wrapping undernath

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment, col

I have a problem with my bootstrap divs, this is my current setup on larger screens:

```
------------------------------------
|                        |     2    |
             1           ------------
|                        |     3    |
------------------------ |          |
                         ------------
```

And my simplified code looks a little like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-ms-12 col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Now unfortunately sometimes Div 2 gets larger and pushes Div 3 lower than the bottom of Div 1 and it wraps underneath. How can I stop this and have Div 3 remain on the right hand side even when lower than Div 1? I've tried clearfix but it doesn't seem to be working!

P.S I'm using that "ms" medium-small breakpoint as an extra breakpoint i've installed.

Comment: Is it possible that your custom `col-ms-*` breakpoint is causing the issue?

Comment: I just removed them to test and I'm still getting the issue, is bootstrap meant to keep the column from wrapping normally then?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/b2m0PUjBHz  - this is the output I'm getting, which is expected.  What is it doing that you think is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `float: right;` property to the third block when the screen width becomes `992px` or more. I've defined a new special class `.pull-md-right` for this purpose.

Please check the result:

[image: result]

```css
/* The heart of the matter */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .pull-md-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

/* Decorations */
.row > div:nth-of-type(1) { background: #9c6; min-height: 200px; }
.row > div:nth-of-type(2) { background: #ff0; min-height: 250px; }
.row > div:nth-of-type(3) { background: #f93; min-height: 150px; }
.row > div {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pull-md-right">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```